# Matching forward slash in regex

Tags: c, regex, debian, posix

I've troubles with preparing regex expression, matching forward slash ('/') inside.

I need to match string like `"/ABC6"` (forward slash, then any 3 characters, then exactly one digit). I tried expressions like `"^/.{3}[0-9]"`, `"^\/.{3}[0-9]"`, `"^\\/.{3}[0-9]"`, `"^\\\\/.{3}[0-9]"` - without success.
How should I do this?

My code:

```
#include <regex.h>        
regex_t regex;
int reti;

/* Compile regular expression */
reti = regcomp(&regex, "^/.{3}[0-9]", 0);
// here checking compilation result - is OK (it means: equal 0)

/* Execute regular expression */
reti = regexec(&regex, "/ABC5", 0, NULL, 0);
// reti indicates no match!
```

NOTE: this is about C language (gcc) on linux (Debian). And of course the expression like `"^\/.{3}[0-9]"` causes gcc compilation warning (unknown escape sequence).

**SOLUTION:** as @tripleee suggested in his answer, the problem was not caused by slash, but by brackets: `'{'` and `'}'`, not allowed in BRE, but allowed in ERE. Finally I changed one line, then all works OK.

```
reti = regcomp(&regex, "^/.{3}[0-9]", REG_EXTENDED);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The slash is fine, the problem is that `{3}` is extended regular expression (ERE) syntax -- you need to pass `REG_EXTENDED` or use `\{3\}` instead (where of course in a C string those backslashes need to be doubled).

Comment: I decided to use REG_EXTENDED - escaping is not as useful, because gcc interpretes escapes during compilation, so probably multi-escaping should be performed ;)

Comment: @VillageTech or you could use string literals https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal with raw strings

Comment: @MichałWalenciak: raw strings are c++ only.